bazel build is failing on macbook m1 pro ( unable to link protobuf)
while trying to run bazel , I am getting the below error, I have protoc installed on my system, Can someone please help me figure out the issue.
➜  go version
go version go1.22.1 darwin/arm64
➜  protoc --version
libprotoc 26.1


ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_anupam/6e9e2a4c19c72b35e7d629ca2e2fa985/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:480:10: Linking external/com_google_protobuf/protoc [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): cc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command (from target @com_google_protobuf//:protoc) external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6-ST-e846b08c7501/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc-2.params

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

with --sandbox_debug
external/zlib/zutil.c:315:20: warning: a function definition without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is not supported in C2x [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
void ZLIB_INTERNAL zcfree (opaque, ptr)
                   ^
3 warnings generated.
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_anupam/6e9e2a4c19c72b35e7d629ca2e2fa985/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:480:10: Linking external/com_google_protobuf/protoc [for tool] failed: (Exit 1): sandbox-exec failed: error executing command
  (cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_anupam/6e9e2a4c19c72b35e7d629ca2e2fa985/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1900/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.2.1/shims:/Users/anupam/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/anupam/.cargo/bin:/Users/anupam/.fzf/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    TMPDIR=/var/folders/w9/s_jqrs9s1d1cq0y3jfh0jwbw0000gn/T/ \
  /usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/var/tmp/_bazel_anupam/6e9e2a4c19c72b35e7d629ca2e2fa985/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1900/sandbox.sb /var/tmp/_bazel_anupam/install/3d6628bc87ba9f6bdce44dfed9a168e8/process-wrapper '--timeout=0' '--kill_delay=15' '--stats=/private/var/tmp/_bazel_anupam/6e9e2a4c19c72b35e7d629ca2e2fa985/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1900/stats.out' external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin_arm64-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6-ST-e846b08c7501/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc-2.params)
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)


«Segmentation fault: 11» something is very bad. Is it possible to make that bazel thing dump detailed logs of what is being run (as from the output, it's hard to see which executable file has actually segfaulted).

Thanks , updated the question with output with --sandbox_debug @kostix

Do any of the results from this search look fishy? I find this one suggesting to somehow add the -ld64 flag to the linker's invocation to be a spot-on. Still, I have no idea how to do that in your particular case (I have zero experience with bazel).

All-in-all, if you'll fail at applying any of the results from the suggested search to your case, I suggest to re-ask your question tagging it clang and xcode as it appears to have zero relation with the Go programming language.
